# how to specify sync-mode and network type while creating docker container using docker go pkg in Golang application?

Tags: docker, go, docker-api

I am trying to create docker container from my golang application using Docker Engine SDKs and Docker API

this is the command i want to implement in my application:

> `docker run --name rinkeby-node ethereum/client-go --rinkeby --syncmode full`

this is the code i am using

```
    ctx := context.Background()
    cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv, client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    imageName := "ethereum/client-go"
    out, err := cli.ImagePull(ctx, imageName, types.ImagePullOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer out.Close()
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, out)


    resp, err := cli.ContainerCreate(ctx, &container.Config{
        Image: imageName,
    }, nil, nil, nil, "containerName")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := cli.ContainerStart(ctx, resp.ID, types.ContainerStartOptions{}); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp.ID)
```

now i want to specify the syncmode to full and the network to rinkeby

Comment: and what is the problem exactly? like are there any errors?

Comment: No no errors,  i want for example  --syncmode full  to be  specified in golang code above 
or --rinkeby  and i don't how to specify this

Comment: you want to access those arguments??

Comment: yes exactly i want to access them and be able to change their values

Comment: for example sync mode could be snap, full or light i want  be able to control which mode the container gonna be in the creation process of the container
the same way we do it here 
docker run --name rinkeby-node ethereum/client-go --rinkeby --syncmode full

but with code in my golang application

Comment: alright in that case you can import `os` package and access them using `os.Args` or even better use https://pkg.go.dev/flag

Comment: What parts of the [`docker run` command syntax](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) do those options correspond to?  Are there corresponding settings in the Go Docker SDK you might set?  What have you already tried?

Comment: @DavidMaze the corresponding setting in the Docker SDK is what mehdy specified in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--syncmode full` and `--rinkeby` flags are the [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) arguments.

So when calling you're calling `ContainerCreate` method inside of `container.Config` add this:

```
Cmd: []string{"--syncmode", "full", "--rinkeby"}
```

For a complete example see [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/examples/)